# FiveM NUI Js normal API request

Tags: javascript, fetch, fivem

I try to make a normal get-request in javascript in a Vue3 side in FiveM NUI.
In chrome everything works just fine but if I open the Page in FiveM nothing loads.

```
fetch("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/postinserat", {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
   body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(res => {
   console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
   this.titel = "";
   this.beschreibung = "";
   this.telefonnummer = "";
   this.preis = "";
   this.currentPage = 0;
   this.getInserate();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Fivem doesn't have fetch function by default so you have to install it trough (Node.js).

- Install node-fetch v2 with `npm i node-fetch@2`
- Add this to very top of your code: `const fetch = require("node-fetch");`

We use v2 because the latest fetch is v3 which uses ES modules that won't work with require.